# Which constructs in Verilog can contain function definition?

Tags: function, verilog, system-verilog

I am new to verilog and trying to figure out **where the function can be defined/declared in verilog** (like I know function can be defined in packages, what else?). Thanks in advance.

Comment: A function can be used anywhere a value is used, or anywhere a procedural statement is allowed. That is almost everywhere.

Comment: @dave_59 where can package be defined/declared?

Comment: @dave_59 Too broad? I've answered it completely (in my opinion) in 72 words.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor, original question was "where can a function be used?"

Comment: @dave_59 Ah. A small edit that completely changes the meaning of the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Verilog**, a function can be declared between

- `module` and `endmodule` (ie in the current region of a module - inside a module, but outside an `initial` or `always` block)
- `generate` and `endgenerate`

That's it.

In **System-Verilog**, a function can be declared between

- `module` and `endmodule`
- `generate` and `endgenerate`

and

- `class` and `endclass`
- `interface` and `endinterface`
- `checker` and `endchecker`
- `package` and `endpackage`
- `program` and `endprogram`

and

- outside a `module` / `interface` / `checker` / `package` / `program`

Answer (score -1):

Probably, easiest way to declare and use function is like, declare all your functions in `<module_function_pkg>.vh` and include that to design verilog file.

Use it as @dave_59 said in comment.